# Excluding user-added files from a folder at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a winforms application. In its folder, (eg .../WinformsApp/Reports), there are several files.

Is there a way to ensure that if the user adds files to this folder, the app will not include them? At the moment the app gets all the files in the folder, but I don't want the app to include user-added folders.

It is possible to say "Get all the files, get a count, if at any time the file count is greater than the previous count ("get a count"), then the user has added files and do whatever.". Would this approach be reliable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all files from the folder, why not just load the specific files you want?  If preventing modifications is absolutely necessary, you could even check against a pre-generated hash on the file count, or some other mechanism to verify that the files are unmodified.

Trying to check the count won't be reliable.  The user could just delete one of yours and add their own, etc.

Comment: Is there an example of generating a hash on the file count in C#? Sorry, this is just something I am not too familiar with.

Comment: @dotnetdev: I was suggesting hashing the file itself - not the count.  Hashing the count won't prevent the issue I raised above.

Comment: Which file? The class itself? Sorry for the naivety!

Comment: @dotnetdev: Each of the files you want to use.  You can load each file, and chech a hash (md5 works for this).  That way, you can verify that hte contents haven't been tweaked...